# Update 1 record according to 2 sorts criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Do you know how can I update 1 record according to 2 sorts criteria?

I have in my table A :

```
id    |     date    | boolean  | data 
-------------------------------------------
001    | 11.13.2017  |    0     | value 1
001    | 09.13.2017  |    1     | value 2
001    | 01.01.2017  |    0     | value 0
002    | 06.15.2017  |    1     | value 3
003    | 04.23.2017  |    1     | value 4
003    | 12.13.2017  |    0     | value 5
```

I would like by id, change the boolean value according with the most recent date.

for example:

```
id     |     date    | boolean  | data 
-------------------------------------------
001    | 11.13.2017  |    1     | value 1 
001    | 09.13.2017  |    0     | value 2
001    | 01.01.2017  |    0     | value 0
```

Thank you

Comment: please edit the post and you don't need to use a `<p>` tag for each paragraph you write, it's implicitly done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the latest record for every ID using row_number. You will need to issue 2 UPDATE statements though, one for updating the latest record to 1 and another one to re-set the others to 0.

Hope the query below answers your query. If you are using true boolean columns, change the values to True and False.

```
DROP TABLE some_tab;

CREATE TABLE some_tab (some_id NUMBER, some_date DATE, some_bool NUMBER, some_data VARCHAR2(50));

INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (001, TO_DATE('11.13.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 0,  'value 1');
INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (001, TO_DATE('09.13.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 1,  'value 2');
INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (001, TO_DATE('01.01.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 0,  'value 0');
INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (002, TO_DATE('06.15.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 1,  'value 3');
INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (003, TO_DATE('04.23.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 1,  'value 4');
INSERT INTO some_tab VALUES (003, TO_DATE('12.13.2017', 'MM.DD.YYYY'), 0,  'value 5');

SELECT * FROM some_tab;

UPDATE some_tab
   SET some_bool = 1
 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT v.r_id
                   FROM (SELECT rowid AS r_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY some_id ORDER BY some_date DESC) AS r_num
                           FROM some_tab) v
                  WHERE v.r_num = 1);

UPDATE some_tab
   SET some_bool = 0
 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT v.r_id
                   FROM (SELECT rowid AS r_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY some_id ORDER BY some_date DESC) AS r_num
                           FROM some_tab) v
                  WHERE v.r_num <> 1);

SELECT * FROM some_tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Updates boolean for recent ID

`UPDATE TableA SET boolean = 1 WHERE date = SELECT date FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowNum,date FROM TableA) AS TableB
WHERE RowNum = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.boolean='True'
FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN  (
     SELECT b.id, max(b.date) AS 'LatestDate'
     FROM tableA AS b
     GROUP BY b.id
 ) as c
 ON a.id=c.id AND a.date=c.LatestDate;
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfb3e8/2